# Keyboard shortucts for Arduino IDE?

Tags: eclipse, arduino

I've just started working on arduino and was wondering about keyboard shortcuts which would make me more efficient in this new environment. Also, I'm acclimated with eclipse. Is there a way to make eclipse shortcuts work on Arduino IDE? Thanks.

Comment: what specific shortcuts?

Comment: @Tim Like jumping to variable and method declarations.

Comment: haven't run across a way to make those work =/ With a 3rd party tool like AutoHotkey you might be able to get something like that set up though. Or a Macroable input device. I have a Nostromo n52 that I've set up with a bunch of programming related macros that I use in various IDEs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about shortcuts on the Arduino IDE, but it is possible to use Eclipse with the Arduino.

Please see the following articles:

- http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/Eclipse
- http://www.baeyens.it/eclipse/